# BASH for loop exiting after calling function

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm working on a bash scripts that will essentially shift the entire contents of a directory, where the filenames all start with a number (0001, 0002, etc). I'm iterating in reverse order through those files to shift the last one down first.

I have one function that iterates through the files and calls another function to actually shift them. When I call the second function, it short-circuits the for loop and exits. I can't figure out why.

```
validation_dir="scripts/validation"
content_directories=($validation_dir "tutorials")

function shift_contents() {
    local start_index=$1
    local positions=$2

    local files=(${validation_dir}/*)
    for ((i=${#files[@]}-1; i>=0; i--)); do
        # Only gets called once
        echo $i
        local f="${files[$i]}"
        local old_index=$(echo $f | tr -dc '0-9' | sed -e 's/^0*//')
        if [ "$old_index" -lt "$start_index" ]
        then
            # Only start when we're at the start index
            continue
        fi
        local new_index=$((old_index + positions))
        # When this is called, it exits the loop
        move_exercise $old_index $new_index
    done
}
```

Here's the function that does the shifting:

```
function move_exercise() {
    local start_index=$1
    local end_index=$2
    local start_prefix=$(echo_filename_prefix $start_index)
    local end_prefix=$(echo_filename_prefix $end_index)

    for i in ${content_directories[@]}; do
        start_file_glob="${i}/${start_prefix}*"

        for f in $start_file_glob; do
            if [ -e $f ]
            then
                start_filename=$f
            else
                log_error "No content found with index ${start_index}"
                exit 1
            fi
            break
        done

        end_file_glob="${i}/${end_prefix}*"

        if [ -e $end_file_glob ]
        then
            log_error "Content was already found for end index ${end_index}: ${end_file_glob}"
            exit 1
        fi

        # Generate the new file name
        new_filename="${start_filename/$start_prefix/$end_prefix}"
        # We get down here once
        echo $start_filename $new_filename
    done

    return
}
```

It looks like the second function is causing the first to exit early, but I don't see how that could happen. See what's going on?

EDIT:

When I run with `bash -x script.sh`, it ends with the following output when it should have one more iteration:

```
+ echo path/to/second-to-last-file new-path
+ return
+ (( i-- ))
+ (( i>=0 ))
```

Does that imply that it's failing the for loop condition check? If so, how could `move_exercise` impact that? If I comment out that line, it works as expected.

Comment: I might be stating the obvious here, but try running your script with -x: `bash -x script.sh`. It's often the best debugging tool for bash scripts.

Comment: The move_exercise function has 2 exit points, is it possible that either one of these points are reached ?

Comment: @Claudiu Not obvious and a good idea. I'm a bash scripting noob.

Comment: @TurboPT I had considered that, but both have logs that would have fired and the program exits with status code 0.

Comment: As an aside, there are a whole bunch of other bugs here that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch (as well as some it may not).

Comment: ...so, let's start on the "bunch of other bugs". I'm assuming you expect `[ -e $globexpr ]` to tell you whether at least one file matching the given glob expression actually exists. However, that's not what it does in practice. If you have *more* than match, then you end up with a command line `[ -e file1 file2 ]`, which is insofar as `[` is concerned simply invalid syntax.

Comment: Moreover, using glob expressions from a variable is a precarious practice in and of itself. It's much more reliable to store the *results* of a glob expression in an array and expand that array. Consider: `dir='/directory/with spaces'` -- you can expand `"$dir"/*.txt` without any problem, but `glob=$dir/*.txt` and then expanding `$glob` will create `/directory/with` as the first result, and `spaces/*.txt` as the second (unless you *also* have a directory named `spaces` with files matching `*.txt` in it, in which case those would result).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is there a CLI equivalent to shellcheck? I'm a developer, but bash scripting seems to have very different conventions from what I'm used to.

Comment: shellcheck itself is a downloadable, installable CLI tool. There's a link to github from the page.

Comment: ...so, the correct approach to store and iterate over glob results is `result=( "$dir"/*.txt )`, and then iterating over `"for item in ${result[@]}"`. I'm not sure what the code surrounding `content_directories` is intended to do, so I'm hard-pressed to say what would be a more correct alternative, but that's another thing that *smells* very wrong; if you intend a two-element array, it may just be `content_directories=( "$validation_dir" scripts )`.

Comment: BTW, the StackOverflow [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) includes a link to "How do I debug a bash script?" (among many other useful resources) that covers `set -x`. Personally, I strongly recommend the [bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) and the Wooledge wiki (home of the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), BashPitfalls page, etc) as good resources, and strongly suggest *avoiding* anything by TLDP.

Comment: (...another aside -- the `function` keyword makes your code noncompliant with POSIX sh, but -- unlike most bashisms -- adds no compensating benefit in return; I suggest avoiding it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `i` to be local, you need to declare it as such:

```
shift_contents() {
  local i
  # ...etc...
}

move_exercise() {
  local i
  # ...etc...
}
```

Otherwise there's only one variable named `i` shared between both functions. When that variable contains a filename, its numeric value is 0 (unless that filename is also the name of a shell variable with a nonzero numeric value assigned) -- so when you decrement it after assigning a filename, it becomes negative.